# How to analyse this with nullor block?

Tags: feedback, negative-feedback

The first is the schematics from NMOS4 with parasitic capacitance:

[image]

I recently read an article on how to analyse the circuit with [The Nullor and Some Applications](https://www.designalog.com/uncategorized-en/the-nullor-and-some-applications-part-i/).

The equivalent nullor circuit. I am not sure this is correct. Can anyone point my error if there is any?

[image]

Comment: In your equivalent nullor circuit, based on the characteristics of the nullor, there is no current flowing through \$R_{S1}\$ and \$R_{f1}\$.

Comment: Also, why do you want to use a nullor? In my opinion, it just complicates the analysis. I know some people said it simplifies opamp circuits, though.

Comment: Hey, that's my article! (of my very infant website). Your model is wrong because there's no series feedback at the output in your actual  NMOS amplifier. I need to find some time to correct this, but if you want, you can always email me.

Comment: @Designalog Please answer with the correct model if you can here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct abstraction of your NMOS common-source amplifier into a nullor. Note, this is an AC representation, which is the reason why I'm connecting \$R_D\$ to ground. You can of course connect it to supply for simulation purposes.

[image: Nullor abstraction of common-source amplifier]

**EDIT:**

You can write 2 equations out of this nullor.
First, the one that will get you transfer function already. Apply KCL at the virtual ground, which is held at 0 due to the nullator at the input which equates both (+) and (-) inputs. I assume \$V_{out}\$ is the output node (top of \$R_{d}\$).

$$
\frac{0-V_{out}}{R_f}+\frac{0-V_{in}}{R_s}=0
$$
After some algebra, we arrive at the well-known inverting amplifier gain equation:
$$
\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=-\frac{R_f}{R_s}
$$

You can write another KCL equation at the output. If assume there's a current \$I_L\$ coming *out* of the (-) terminal of the nullor output, then this will divide over \$R_f\$ and \$R_d\$.
$$
I_L = \frac{V_{out}}{R_D}+\frac{V_{out}}{R_f} = V_{out}\left(\frac{1}{R_D}+\frac{1}{R_f}\right)
$$

However, all this is saying is that the current at the output of the nullor is given by \$V_{out}\$ divided by the parallel combination of \$R_D\$ and \$R_f\$. Well, that's expected as the load current will depend on the loading conditions of the amplifier, BUT NOT the output voltage... that's the whole point of a voltage amplifier.

Comment: It looks like this is positive feedback according to your nullor  circuit.

Comment: @kile Nope. As long as there's an inversion from the virtual ground to the output, it's still negative feedback. I'll give you that it's not conventional to present it like that, though. You can simply flip the nullor symbol vertically or horizontally to get the conventional picture back.

Comment: your nullor circuit  will give \$V_{out}  = - \frac{V_{in}} {R_S} R_D \$.

Comment: @kile no it won't. Please see my edit.

Comment: @Designalog If we assume the ideal opamp with infinite gain in the original circuit, we would easily see that \$V_{GS} = 0\$ and \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = -\frac{R_f}{R_s}\$. Just out of curiosity, as you probably work a lot with nullors, could you share some experiences on the advantages of using nullors?

Comment: @internet of course, because we're solving an idealized nullor, and any single ended input stage would already impress a DC voltage between the + and - inputs.

Comment: @internet I'd say for any feedback configuration with an output voltage, the typical op-amp is sufficient. However, when we need series feedback, most book authors solve this by using a transistor at the output (like a feedback opamp current source). This is a valid implementation, but not the only possible one.

Comment: @internet the point is to abstract the amplifier as much as possible before going into a transistor implementation. I was taught to reason for implementations rather searching for solutions first. Not to say that searching is bad, but if you have a tool that allows you to create and not constraint you, then I'm in favor of it. Check the thesis of Ernst Nordholt.

Comment: @internet also, nullors adapt nicely to abstract double loop design, which are used to produce accurate input or output impedances. Good luck abstracting that with the 3-terminal op-amp symbol.

Comment: @Designalog Thanks for sharing. I'll check them out.

Answer (score 1):

About Nullor:
[image]
ANALYSIS OF A CIRCUIT IN THE PRESENCE OF NULLORS
a) each nullor must be replaced with a pair of norator and nullator bipoles;
b) each nullator must be replaced with a (virtual) short circuit or open circuit;
c) each norator must be replaced with a voltage or current generator with an unknown impressed quantity;
d) write the solving system with the desired method (nodes, links, cuts); it will turn out that such a system will have a
number of unknowns superior to equations since each norator introduces an unknown impressed quantity;
e) write for each nullator an additional constraint equation:\
1) if the nullator has been replaced by a short-circuit then the null current condition must be imposed on it;
2) if the nullator has been replaced by an open circuit then the zero voltage condition must be imposed at its terminals.
f) after adding the constraint conditions, the system will be made up
of a number of equations equal to the unknowns.
Analysis on a mesh basis:
a) every nullor must be replaced by the two bipoles nullor and
norator;\
b) each nullator must be replaced with a short-circuit
and each norator a voltage generator with unknown impressed
voltage.
c) write the zero current constraint equation for each
nullator. Possibly ensure that the nullator is on the co-tree.
Example:
[image]